# How to produce the same string for x number of lines and paste 2 files? unix

Tags: unix, text-files, echo, paste, cat

How to produce the same string for x number of lines and then use paste to combine the files:
I have a file as such with unknown number of lines, e.g.:

```
$ echo -e "a\tb\tc\nd\te\tf" > in.txt
$ cat in.txt
a   b   c
d   e   f
```

I want to concat the files with a new column that has the same string for every row. I have tried using echo to create a file and then using paste to concat the columns but i have to know the number of rows in `in.txt` first and then create a `in2.txt` using echo.

```
$ echo -e "a\tb\tc\nd\te\tf" > in.txt
$ cat in.txt
a   b   c
d   e   f
$ echo -e "x\nx\n" > in2.txt
$ paste in.txt in2.txt
a   b   c   x
d   e   f   x
```

**How else can I achieve the same output for an unknown number of lines in `in.txt`?**, e.g.

**[in:]**

```
a   b   c
d   e   f
```

**[out:]**

```
a   b   c   x
d   e   f   x
```

My data consist of a million lines with 3 columns in `in.txt` of 50-200 chars for each line, so solution needs to keep the "big" data size in mind.

Comment: Please explain why just changing every line using `sed` isn't possible (e. g. `sed 's/$/\tx/'`).

Comment: it's possible to use sed but i would rather not mess with the encoding that comes from different unix environment. the default encoding for all files should remain as utf8

Comment: `sed` in itself has no problem with utf8 encodings.  It can work on bytestreams and ignore the encodings completely.  Furthermore, utf8 is compatible to ASCII if the string in question is just a simple thing like `x`, so using it will work fine.  I can imagine that you have additional restrictions you haven't told us about which still rule out `sed`, but imagining won't help find a solution ;-)  So maybe you tell us a little more about the reason why `sed` should not work for your case …

Comment: `sed` did the same job too =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `join`:

```
echo | join input - -a 1 -o "1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1" -e x
```

Though just doing a `sed` replace should be much better.